# Сохранение фрейма временных рядов с экономией памяти

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

У меня в бд лежит куча данных после обработки получается массив 4974917х256х91. Скорее всего после добавления массив перезаписывается но проверить отмасштабированные данные пока не понимаю как.

Мне нужна подсказка, как правильно сохранять данные в Pandas или NumPy?

Беру из бд определённые данные(временной ряд)

```py
df = pd.read_sql(sql=f"""SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY date;""", con=engine)
```

если есть пропуски разделяю данные

```py
df2 = df.iloc[i[0]:i[1]]
```

делаю копию потому-что для добавления нужно проверять на вхождение параметров

```py
train_scaled = df2.copy()
```

после чего масштабирую

```py
train_scaled[mm[0]] =  df2[mm[0]].apply(lambda x: (x - float(mm[1])) / (float(mm[2]) - float(mm[1])))
train_scaled = train_scaled.iloc[:-1].values
```

дальше происходит магия

```py
X_train = []
X_train.append(train_scaled[i-window:i])
```

[image: 13 гигов]

```py
X_train2 = np.array(X_train[:int((len(X_train) / 100) * 5)], dtype=np.float32)
```

выжирает больше 40 гигов памяти. Я не против если бы был уверен в правильности данных.

Подскажите как это сделать правильно. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А магия-то в чем?  Какой объем датафрейма df? Какой объем датафрейма train_scaled?